# Problems in UTC time (unix timestamp) convert to human readable format then merge the other data

Tags: python-3.x, unix-timestamp, converters

I had used the API to get a data and then asign

to "sol_tvl_df" class.

```
from defillama import DefiLlama
import requests
import pandas
import ccxt
from math import sqrt
import time
import json
from typing import List, Union
import numpy

_binance = ccxt.binanceusdm()

BASE_URL = "https://api.llama.fi"

class DefiLlama:
    """
    DeFi Llama class to act as DeFi Llama's API client.
    All the requests can be made through this class.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize the object
        """
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def _send_message(self, method, endpoint, params=None, data=None):
        url = BASE_URL + endpoint
        response = self.session.request(method, url, params=params, data=data, timeout=30)
        return response.json()
    
sol_tvl_df = DefiLlama()._send_message('GET', '/charts/solana' )
```

After API request, then I got thos data as below:

```
print (sol_tvl_df)

[{'date': '1616025600', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 148988798.24},
 {'date': '1616112000', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 153204288.86},
 {'date': '1616198400', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 147690914.44},
 {'date': '1616284800', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 151935325.31},
 {'date': '1616371200', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 152981122.24},
 {'date': '1616457600', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 162065402.5018374},
 {'date': '1616544000', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 156101310.64592892},
 {'date': '1616630400', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 144439504.2605513},
 {'date': '1616716800', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 135610450.40169644},
 {'date': '1616803200', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 147786656.29307032},
 {'date': '1616889600', 'totalLiquidityUSD': 172583243.64011288}
 .............]
```

Now, I want to select all part of 'date' to convert to date format of iso8601 for human readable status like

2022-03-22 00:00:00+00:00 then maybe let them to merge into the other data.

I tried so many times and google it, but I didn't get answer.

Would you guys help me, please

I have tried this:

```
ts_int_list = ( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in sol_tvl_df ) )
ts_int_list = ts_int_list.get(date)
```

Comment: Have you read through the documentation from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: oh...I didn't read it yet. Since, first step, I don't know how to select all of UTC data and then assign to a class. after that, will go to date time processing.